# How to pinch zoom in/out and pan around in LinearLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming

In my android app, I have a linearlayout where I put many linearlayouts with images in it. It will go past the screen border horizontally and vertically.

I want the user to pinch zoom in or out and pan around. I tried putting it in a horizontal scroll and vertical scroll, but it wont let me zoom, and I can only move in 1 direction at 1 time, like it wont let me move diagonally.

I tried this plugin
https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/downloads/list

But it won't let me pan around. It only lets me do it on the stuff thats visible on the screen...

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Would take some work, but just save the real size of layout and current zoom, then multiplicate every time user changes the zoom to change layoutparams size

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is to put your images in  HTML and use webview to display it.Webview automatically handles zooming and panning of content.

Comment: but i also add click and long click events to the images

Comment: you can do this in webview using javascript which will call your native code.refer-http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: But I don't want internet to use this, I need to do this all locally.

Comment: Ya u can do this locally..go through the tutorial

Comment: @omega don't let the `Web` portion of `WebView` fool you. You don't need to be connected to the internet to utilize web view. I am with rupesh on this one, if there is an option outside of using WebView it is likely to be a HUGE headache.